# Unlink non-logged on account from Microsoft in Windows 10

Tags: windows, security, registry, sam

One of my customers got hacked big time: Hotmail (where it probably started), Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat. She couldn't log on to her computer anymore, since her password on her Microsoft account has been changed by the hacker.
I enabled the Administrator account, and gained access to the data.
Now I am looking for a way to unlink the local user account from Microsoft, so I can log in to her own account.
I have access to her files, but not to her account.

Is there any way to unlink a local account without being logged on?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, or rather, a workaround:

1. I booted the computer from a Windows USB-stick, chose "Repair", "Advanced" and then "Command Prompt"
2. I changed drive and directory to the System32 folder on the volume Windows was installed
3. I renamed utilman.exe to utilman_old.exe and copied cmd.exe to utilman.exe
4. I restarted the computer normally with boot from harddisk/ssd.
5. At the logon screen, I clicked the button for Accessibility Options, which normally invokes utilman.exe. However, utilman.exe is now a copy of cmd.exe, so an ELEVATED command prompt is started
6. I wrote the line "net users administrator active=yes"
7. I rebooted the computer, and at login, I chose the Administrator account that was located at the bottom left of the login screen
8. I downloaded ProfileWizard from https://www.forensit.com/downloads.html, installed it an ran it
9. I selected the profile, that was linked to the Microsoft account, and clicked Next
10. I opened an elevated Command Prompt, and wrote "net users tempuser /add"
11. I went back to Profile Wizard, and wrote "tempuser", and clicked "Next"
12. At finish, the current administrator user was logged of, and logged on again. I logged administrator off, and logged on as "tempuser". I then had full access to the account that was linked to a Microsoft account, but now as a local account.

Comment: If you do this, please remember to repeat step 1 and 2, then delete utilman.exe and rename utilman_old.exe to utilman.exe, to restore the Accessibilty Options (and prevent unauthorized use of admin privileges).

Comment: And if you accidentally linked your Administrator account to a Microsoft account then exchange line 6 with following:
6a. net users newadmin /add
6b net localgroups administrators newadmin /add

And log on as newadmin in step 7